# Python divide odd number to closest integers

Tags: python, integer, divide

I would love to have a oneligner (if not possible; ok) that divides a odd number by 2, and gives the 2 closest integers with Python 2.7:

```
9/2 results in 4,5

7/2 results in 3,4
```

etc.

I've tried, but I couldn't think of any simple solution.

Comment: `9//2,9//2 + 1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div_odd = lambda n: (n//2, n//2 + 1)
```

Comment: python 3 would need `//` - `lambda n: (n//2, n//2 + 1)`

Comment: // is generally faster than / it seems.

Comment: And `//` works down to Python 2.2 I believe, so if you need floor division to work in both 2 & 3 just use that.

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import ceil, floor
closest_ints = (int(floor(9/2)), int(ceil(9/2)))
```

I guess you could wrap it in a function.

EDIT: I assumed Python 3 integer division, in Python 2 add

```
from __future__ import division
```